How to handle Supabase createServerClient & createBrowserClient in NextJS in an API file?
So I'm using @supabase/ssr to handle SSR with NextJS.
I like to keep my API functions centralised into one api folder/file, so that I don't have to go looking for different queries in different components. The issue I ran into right now is that for every request, I have to create two separate versions that each use either createServerClient or createBrowserClient.
I obviously don't want to keep doing this because it's too much overhead for no reason, so I thought let's conditionally check for isServer ? createServerClient : createBrowserClient. The problem is that my createServerClient also imports cookies from Next (import { cookies } from "next/headers";), which causes an error any time I try to import the createServerClient client anywhere that is not server-compatible (because it depends the cookies modules).
I don't know what to do now, the only solution I can think of is to pass the client to every API function as a parameter, but I just find that so cumbersome and it feels like there has to be a better/more efficient way. I hope anyone has a better solution!
I've also tried conditional importing, but that also doesn't work (still getting cookies import error)
import isServer from "@/utils/isServer";

const supabaseClient = isServer()
  ? import("@/services/supabase/clients/server").then(
      (module) => module.default
    )
  : import("@/services/supabase/clients/browser").then(
      (module) => module.default
    );

export default supabaseClient;

